# Order posts by category name

Tags: categories, order

Is there any way to order posts by category name?

I tried

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'dlm_download',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order_by'=> 'cat', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

But it does not really work, could please someone give me a hint?

Comment: This doesn't work because 'cat' is not a param for orderby. Please check the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for more details.

Comment: Nor is `order_by` a valid argument. [It should be `orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). What you are wanting to do is not simple, as you can see from the number of unanswered "RELATED" posts on the right.

Comment: You can try the plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-order-category/

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "order posts by category" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same struggle like you, thank i sat down and rethought the whole thing, what you actually need to is select all the categories, and pass the category id to it.

Since you use a dlm_download you will need to do the following, get the terms from the dlm_download_category

```
$cats = get_terms('dlm_download_category');
```

Loop trough the category and pass `query_posts` in it

so

```
foreach ($cats as $cat) 
{

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'dlm_download',
'dlm_download_category' => $cat->slug,
);

query_posts($args);

if (have_posts()) : 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
// your stuff here
endwhile;
endif; 
}
```

And there you go

PS: if you want to make it with `posts` not with `custom post`

Than `$cats = get_categories();`

and pass `'cat'` in to the argument.

Hope its clear and helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you could have multiple categories assigned to a single post. In that case, which category is the order based off of?

One work around would be to create a script that stores the category name in a meta value, and use the `orderby=meta_value` to create the proper order.

Comment: Sounds good at first but, since the actual posts will have multiple categories that's the main problem. If i would do a script selecting all the categories, will generate huge page load and sounds a bit pointless, i tested with one category actually with meta_value still does not work