# Related categories order posts by category

Tags: wp-query, categories, custom-taxonomy

How do I order following custom posts by category like so:

**Cat title**

player 1

player 2

**Cat title 2**

Player 5

player 7

As far to the code below is where my knowledge goes so any advise is very much appreciated!

```
<?php
                $player_tax_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'players_cat', array('fields' => 'ids') );
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'        => 'players',
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                    'tax_query'        => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'players_cat',
                            'field'    => 'id',
                            'terms'    => $player_tax_terms
                        )
                    ),
                    'post__not_in'     => array ($post->ID),
                    'meta_key'         => 'player_number',
                    'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order'            => 'ASC'
                );
                $related_items = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ($related_items->have_posts()) : while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post(); ?>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="cell player">

                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>

                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>

                        <?php else: ?>
                            <figure class="avatar"></figure>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="title">
                            <?php the_title( '<h5>', '</h5>' ) ?>
                            <?php if( get_field('player_position') ): ?>
                                <p><?php the_field('player_position'); ?></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if( get_field('player_number') ): ?>
                            <span><?php the_field('player_number'); ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>

                <?php endwhile; endif;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Anyone knows how to do it? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple hurdles to handle ...

1) You can have multiple Category codes for each post, so they are not normal query variables (not really a hurdle - but you may get repeat occurrances of the same post under multiple categories).

2) Category titles are 1 linkage 'further' away (in terms of SQL queries) than the category code. i.e. the post is connected to the Category code(s), then those codes are connected to the code titles. This is more of a challenge.

[THIS POST](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142268/order-posts-by-category-name) shows a similar issue with a solution of getting all the categories, then running a filtered query for each category, and displaying the post list for that category. Perhaps that is close enough to what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it be better to use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) relationship fiels? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Comment: ACF makes creating custom fields simpler, but it would not make a complex query like the one in the question simpler. So no, it would not help for the above question. (The sample in the link provided presents custom elements for a post, rather than posts for an (custom) element.)